# AngularJS application cant read local text file even after deployed on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis

I have 4 files(in same directory) in my application which is deployed on IIS-

1. home.html
2. Angular.js
3. data.txt
4. web.config (Auto generated by IIS for default document)

I want show content of 'data.txt' on 'home.html'.
Same code runs at [Plunker][1]

This 'home.html' file have below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
<title>nitin</title>
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nameSpace = angular.module("app", []);
    nameSpace.controller("GuitarFunction", function ($scope) {});
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="GuitarFunction">     
    <ng-include src="'data.txt'">
    </ng-include>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8aBJsqzV07AweDk4PAcG?p=preview

Comment: If you check your browser console.. are you seeing any error there related to cross-origin ?

Comment: at Anonymous function (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:10453:7)
   at sendReq (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:10333:9)
   at serverRequest (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:10045:9)
   at processQueue (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:14567:11)
   at Anonymous function (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:14583:27)  
   at bootstrapApply (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:1633:9)
   at invoke (file:///C:/inetpub/Projects/ng-include/angular.js:4450:7)

Answer (score 0):

Website needs to be hosted in a web server (IIS, Apache), so it can be provided over http/https.

Browser security measures will prevent script from loading external resources if the protocol is file://.

If you hosted C:\webapp in IIS on port 5000 for example, you need to direct your browser to http://localhost:5000/index.html and not to C:\webapp\index.html.

Comment: I already browse the link as http://localhost:81/ng-include/ here error comes in angular.js file as "SCRIPT5007:Object expected"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the overwrite in the web.config if your website do not have a server code then your overwrite its just the name of the application like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
  </handlers>
  <rewrite>
       <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <conditions>
                      <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
       </rules>
  </rewrite>
```